# Java Google Youtube Data API:: Unauthorized

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-data-api

I wanted to upload a video on youtube using Java Google Data API. I got the following cod from the Google Data Api documentation to upload a video.The only thing i need to change in this code in Client ID and Porduct key. i am using followinf method to authenticate

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID, developer_key);

Client key is my Google Email id , tried with with wasy,

- only provided Username e,g. "sampleuser"
- or complete Gmail id e.g. "sampleuser@gmail.com" or "smapleuser@googlemail.com"

i got developer key by logging my Google mail id as mentioned "smapleuser@googlemail.com"

but i always got following exception

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unauthorized
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:600)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:400)
at YouTube.videoUpload(YouTube.java:115)
at YouTube.main(YouTube.java:43)
```

here is my code for video Upload

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("sampleuser@gmail.com",
            "fakegoogleapplicationidjsuttoshowthatimgivingidhere");
    // YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("My Application");
    VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

    YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
    mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
    mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent("My Test Movie");
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Autos"));
    mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
    mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("cars");
    mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("funny");
    mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
    mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent("My description");
    mg.setPrivate(false);
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "mydevtag"));
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "anotherdevtag"));

    newEntry.setGeoCoordinates(new GeoRssWhere(37.0,-122.0));
    // alternatively, one could specify just a descriptive string
    // newEntry.setLocation("Mountain View, CA");

    MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(new File("D:\\maths.mp4")
    , "video/quicktime");
    newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);

    // "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
    String uploadUrl =
        "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

    try {
        VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please help , unable to find solution. thank you so much..looking for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

`service.setUserCredentials("email_here", "password_here");`